# Am I closing too many questions?

Tags: discussion, moderation, vote-to-close

Looking at the [2022 year in moderation report](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1825/755), I noticed that it lists moderators as closing many more questions than community users.  So, I wanted to solicit feedback.  Do you see me as closing too many questions?  Should I be leaving it to the community to close questions?  I'd welcome your thoughts.  Thank you.

---

P.S. You can compare to the [2021 year in moderation report](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1787/755), if you like.

Comment: Any tips on how to interpret the data? I mean, of course, I can look at the stats and see that $a \gg b$, but what of it? Looking at the previous years, the numbers fluctuate wildly.

Comment: @Dmitry, I am not sure.  I have heard a position that says moderators should not close posts, because then the community gets out of the habit of taking care of closing.  Or, perhaps prefer having closable questions be closed quicker.  I don't know what is healthiest for the site.

Comment: I don't think we've had quite sufficient community moderation in the history of the site. Not sure how we'd switch gears _now_. ‎